# How should I ignore all the node_modules directory of all the project at once?

Tags: github, node-modules, mern, gitignore

Let say, if I want to push multiple MERN project to a single repository on Github then how should I ignore all the node_modules directory of all the project at once?

I don't know how can I do that.

Can anyone tell me how can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

[Docs:](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format)

> If there is a separator at the beginning or middle (or both) of the pattern, then the pattern is relative to the directory level of the particular `.gitignore` file itself. Otherwise the pattern may also match at any level below the `.gitignore` level.

So, in your `.gitignore` at the root of your repository,

- `/node_modules` ignores the `node_modules` in the root of the repository
- `node_modules` ignores the `node_modules` anwhere in the repository

---

EDIT: From the same documentation link:

> A `gitignore` file specifies intentionally untracked files that Git should ignore. Files already tracked by Git are not affected

Once you add the files, ignore doesn't anything for you any more. This is what seems to have happened for you. You did not just need an ignore, as you stated: you needed to actively remove them from tracking first. Once they are untracked, `.gitignore` will behave as outlined above.

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution of the problem.
This is the solution that worked for me.

Cache Clearing: Sometimes, Git may have cached the node_modules folders before you added them to .gitignore. In such cases, you need to clear the cached files. Run the following commands in your terminal:

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -m "Remove cached files"
```

This will remove the cached files and update the Git repository.